# Magento 2 - Layered navigation Parent and Child Category Filter issue

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, category-tree

I am using WeltPixel layered navigation Free extension. In category filter, third level categories was not showing in filter navigation by default. I added some code to get third level categories.

```
protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        if (!$this->_moduleHelper->isEnabled()) {
            return parent::_getItemsData();
        }

        /** @var \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();

        if ($this->_isFilter) {
            $productCollection = $productCollection->getCollectionClone()
                ->removeAttributeSearch('category_ids');
        }

        $optionsFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData('category');
        $category           = $this->dataProvider->getCategory();
        $categories         = $category->getChildrenCategories();

        $collectionSize = $productCollection->getSize();

        if ($category->getIsActive()) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $count = isset($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]) ? $optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count'] : 0;
                if ($category->getIsActive()
                    && $this->_layerFilter->isOptionReducesResults($this, $count, $collectionSize)
                ) {
                 $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                        $this->escaper->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        $category->getId(),
                        $count
                    );
                }
                // added for child categories
             $cat = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category->getId());
                $sub_category = $cat->getChildrenCategories();

                foreach ($sub_category as $category) {
                    if ($category->getIsActive()
                            && isset($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()])
                            && $this->isOptionReducesResults($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count'], $collectionSize)
                        ) 
                    {
                      $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                            $this->escaper->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                            $category->getId(),
                            $optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count']
                        );
                    }
                } //
               // end child categories code
        }
    }
return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
    }
}
```

Child categories are now showing, but the issue is all parent & child categories are showing in single ol li list. Screenshots

[image]

Category List HTML

[image]

How to identify Parent and child categories using above code?

Comment: I have same issue. Do you fix it?

Comment: No. I am using another layered navigation extension.

Comment: Ok , Thank you!